# Transfer files between android devices using WIFI direct

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to build an application that can transfer files between android devices using WIFI direct. I does have to be p2p connection, I just want to send pictures.
I tried:

1. https://github.com/mayfourth/WiFi-Direct-File-Transfer - it didn't work
2. http://www.androidside.com/docs/resources/samples/WiFiDirectDemo/index.html - It gave me an error at this `String localIP = Utils.getLocalIPAddress();` code.
3. [How can I transfer files between Android devices using Wi-Fi Direct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25638335/how-to-transfer-files-between-android-devices-using-wifi-direct) - didn't work

Comment: you may want to include your code and the logcat error that you're getting

Comment: you have need to get file from sd card and then encode that file then post that file to server this is easy use soap Parsing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google provides a working demo App allows users to send a picture via WiFi Direct. They explain all the necessary steps and provides you with the whole source code which you can find here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html

I imported the code and tested it on different phones. When you run the App on the 2 phones, you press the scan button on both of them. Then you connect one of them to the other. One of them would be the phone where you need to select the image that you wish to send. The other will be waiting to receive it.

Note: WiFi Direct between different types of phones does not really work properly. For example, if you run the App between a Samsung and a Nexus, the connection might not be successful. So I advice you to test it between 2 Samsung which from my experience have a reliable WiFi Direct connection and support.

Hope this helps, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, Yeah I will try to work on that and see what come up

Comment: Hello Ziad , you told about importing code and testing on devices, you mean code from this site: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html and you manually wrote your own app, or you found maybe app on github and download from github for testing? if you have link with this app on github can you share it please :)

Comment: i have go through the code facing a liitle bit of problem while understanding and sendinf the file